# pop up delete sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, sweetalert2

i am trying to do pop up delete action with sweetalert2 in asp.net core project

it seems delete befor the pop up it self

but not working

JS:

```
jQueryAjaxDelete = form => {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure to delete this  of ?",
        text: "Delete Confirmation?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Delete",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                $('#view-all').html(res.html);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
       })
  }  ) 
};
```

**in view**

```
     <form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxDelete(this)" class="d-inline">
                                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                                                <input type="submit" value="Supprimer" class="btn btn-danger" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the result from a promise, like this:

```
jQueryAjaxDelete = form => {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure to delete this  of ?",
        text: "Delete Confirmation?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Delete",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then(value) => {
        // also be aware you need to check the "value" variable
        // to see if the user answered YES
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                $('#view-all').html(res.html);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
       });
  };
```

Comment: thank u for replaying  (JS) ';' expected. in here  .then(value) => {

Comment: no lock bros ; it delete directly

Comment: I corrected the syntax issue

Comment: i got blanc page with this {"isValid":true,"html":"\r\n\r\n\u003Cdiv class=\u0022row\u0022\u003E\r\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022col-11\u0022\u003E\r\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022card\u0022\u003E\r\n            \u003Cdiv class=\u0022card-body\u0022\u003E\r\n                \u003Cdiv class=

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you with every issue you have in your web page.  I am only answering the problem you were having with sweetalert.  If you have another problem, you may want to post a new question with a minimal reproducible example.  And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: still nothing bros