# pop up confirm delete in net core mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, sweetalert, sweetalert2

i am trying to do pop up delete action with sweetalert2 in asp.net core project

it seems delete befor the pop up it self

but not working

JS:

```
jQueryAjaxDelete = form => {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure to delete this  of ?",
        text: "Delete Confirmation?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Delete",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }).then((confirm) => {
        if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?'))
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                $('#view-all').html(res.html);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    });
};
```

**in view**

```
     <form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxDelete(this)" class="d-inline">
                                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                                                <input type="submit" value="Supprimer" class="btn btn-danger" />
 </form>
```

i got this proplem
https://i.ibb.co/64sZ2YX/Capture.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pop up delete sweetalert2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081933/pop-up-delete-sweetalert2)

Comment: no  bros did not